# How to get current location without using delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, location, cllocationmanager

For some reasons, I hope to get the current location without using the delegate method.
Is there some solutions which can get the current location just from CLLocationManager?

Comment: What's the problem with delegate ?

Comment: Do you have a mapView in your controller?

Comment: No, I just need get the user's current location, and then upload it to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use **location** method of CLLocationManager class which will return last known location of device.

`manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [manager location];`

Answer (score 4):

Check below links , those are the good Implementation of location update with `Block` :

https://github.com/ideaismobile/AKLocationManager

https://github.com/axldyb/CLLocationManager-blocks

https://github.com/keithpitt/DKLocationManager

Even you can use `NSNotificationCenter` for it ,

Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16173504/2919739

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I need some time to have a look carefully.

Comment: Welcome bro and ya don't forget to accept my answer If you find it useful :)